# Replace object in list with viewmodel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Scenario: I have a Webservice that gets some feedback sent from my users. The `Feedback` class has a User. In the ViewModel I get the complete list of feedback sent by users and bind to it in the view and I want bind to the User in the list to show who sent that feedback. Nothing unusual here. However, I want to add some controls to the user so that when you click it you have some actions and I want to use this control in several places in the app.

Problem: To me it's obvious I need to create a `UserView` and `UserViewModel` with the appropriate actions. But how would I go about replacing the user in the `Feedback` class with a `ViewModel`? Or is there any other recommended way (like creating a converter that returns the `UserViewModel` to a `ContentPresenter`)?

I'm using a custom MVVM framework based on the "[Build Your Own MVVM Framework](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX10/EX15)" talk at MIX10 (just so you know, doing this as an exercise to learn more about MVVM and keep the Framework simple and fast).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caliburn.Micro is the end result of that MIX10 talk, and it automatically binds up  `ContentControl`s to a the resolved view and viewmodel

You can follow the same approach:

Make the child VM a property of the parent VM...(as someone has already answered)

```
public class UserViewModel 
{
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class FeedbackViewModel 
{ 
    public UserViewModel UserView { get; set; }
}
```

Then use `ContentControl` to allow the child VM to be injected into the parent view:

```
<UserControl x:Name="ParentView"> 
    <StackPanel>
       <TextBlock>Some Parent View Content here...</TextBlock>
       <!-- Now the child content: -->
       <ContentControl x:Name="UserView" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

I assume since you have based your framework on Robs original talk, it is automatically binding properties based on convention? If so the same approach is taken here. The convention for `ContentControl` is a little different from the rest as can be seen in the docs:

> The convention for ContentControl is a bit interesting. If the item we
>   are binding to is not a value type and not a string, then we assume
>   that the Content is a ViewModel. So, instead of binding to the Content
>   property as we would in the other cases, we actually set up a binding
>   with CM’s custom attached property: View.Model. This property causes
>   CM’s ViewLocator to look up the appropriate view for the view model
>   and CM’s ViewModelBinder to bind the two together. Once that is
>   complete, we pop the view into the ContentControl’s Content property.
>   This single convention is what enables the powerful, yet simple
>   ViewModel-First composition in the framework.

The code for this convention is:

```
AddElementConvention<ContentControl>(ContentControl.ContentProperty, "DataContext", "Loaded").GetBindableProperty =
            delegate(DependencyObject foundControl) 
            {
                var element = (ContentControl)foundControl;

                if (element.Content is DependencyObject && !OverwriteContent)
                    return null;
#if SILVERLIGHT
                var useViewModel = element.ContentTemplate == null;
#else
                var useViewModel = element.ContentTemplate == null && element.ContentTemplateSelector == null;
#endif
                if (useViewModel) {
                    Log.Info("ViewModel bound on {0}.", element.Name);
                    return View.ModelProperty;
                }

                Log.Info("Content bound on {0}. Template or content was present.", element.Name);
                return ContentControl.ContentProperty;
            };
```

As you can see the `Content`/`ContentTemplate` is checked to see if it's a visual element, and if not it's assumed to be a VM. The bindable property is then returned as either the VM itself (in the case that no content template was set) or the content itself.

Might be worth reading through that for some more ideas:

http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens%2c%20Conductors%20and%20Composition&referringTitle=Documentation

(scroll to Quasi-Conductors section)

As for doing this all over your app to get `Users` replaced with ViewModels - I think that's just a case of slogging through it

You could use a view-first approach and maybe convert the datacontext to a VM via a factory when resolving the VM, but it would just get messy! (I don't like the idea of mixed View-First and ViewModel-First approaches much unles absolutely necessary)

Comment: Might be the solution for now no matter how messy :( Unfortunately the Solution has more than 4 years of coding with 4 guys working everyday. This is a healthcare product so you can imagine that it has a really complex model. And doing the View-First approach in the particular case would go a long way.

Comment: Well the bonus is that you have this as your own framework, so you can put a special set of conventions in for View-First bindings, look at the source and pass it through some sort of factory that examines the model type and returns the model wrapped in a VM. It's messy but it sounds like it would cut the amount of work down tenfold

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create wrapper view models to contain the feedback and user models in order to add functionality to it.

This yields two classes: the FeedbackViewModel and the UserViewModel. Omitting property notification:

```
 public class UserViewModel {

     public User User { get; set; }
     public ICommand UserAction { get; set; }
     ...
 }

 public class FeedbackViewModel { 

     public UserViewModel User { get; set; }
     public Feedback Feedback { get; set; }
     public ICommand FeedbackAction { get; set; }
     ...
 }
```

You could use some kind of factory to convert your feedback collection and users into the view models that wrap the model objects.

Comment: I was afraid of that... :( My model is very complex (many other modules and classes with the User in several places). It isn't really feasible to do that in the entire solution. Your answer is correct, but I may need an alternative. Thank you Bas Brekelmans.